# how to modify a python library function

Tags: python

In the python module fitter there is a function called:

```
    def fit(self, progress=False, n_jobs=-1, max_workers=-1):
    
    import warnings

    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)

    N = len(self.distributions)
    with tqdm_joblib(desc=f"Fitting {N} distributions", total=N) as progress_bar:
        Parallel(n_jobs=max_workers, backend='threading')(delayed(self._fit_single_distribution)(dist) for dist in self.distributions)


    self.df_errors = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "sumsquare_error": self._fitted_errors,
            "aic": self._aic,
            "bic": self._bic,
            "kl_div": self._kldiv,
            "ks_statistic": self._ks_stat,
            "ks_pvalue": self._ks_pval,
        }
    )
```

I want to change it and remove the progress bar. However, I cannot change this file, it is only for reading. How could I modify it?

Comment: Why does the `progress=False` parameter appear to do nothing? You could submit a merge request to the repo with a fix

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the function is called in a context in which you patch `tqdm_joblib` to produce a `contextlib.nullcontext` instead.

```
import unitest.mock
import contextlib

null_context = contextlib.nullcontext()


with unittest.mock.patch('fitter.tqdm_joblib', return_value=null_context):
    # your code that invokes fit(...)
```

You can wrap this into a decorator that you can manually apply to `fit` make the patch automatically whenever it gets run.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def disable_progress_bar(ContextDecorator):
     with unittest.mock.patch('fitter.tqdm_joblib', return_value=null_context):
         yield


fitter.fit = disable_progress_par(fitter.fit)
```

Comment: That sounds like it should be a PR to the library more than a solution to the question

Comment: Well, not this exact code (if I were a maintainer, I'd reject a pull request that used `unittest.mock` to patch `fit`) :) I'm picturing this as a change for a single script, not something you would require, say, a fork of the library until a proper feature to disable the progress bar could get merged.

Comment: Of course. Internally the change might be done with a simple conditional. It appears that the function argument is already there, just unused